# How can I change a body tag ID based on the page title in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Ruby on Rails (5) I want to use an if statement to change the ID of the body tag based on what view I am rendering. 
Specifically I want to use a background image on my home page only, and not on any other. I want this to fill the screen, but if I put it on the page it's self it comes up with a border. So I want to attache it to the body tag in the application.html.erb view so the ID will tell CSS to load the background image. But I can't get the :title to tell ERB that it is there and make the statement true.

I am using provide on the view page as so:

```
<% provide(:title, "Home") %>
```

Then in the application.html.erb page I am trying to use an if statement to put in the body tag with or without the CSS ID for the background image based on the provided :title, like so:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= yield(:title) %></title>
    ...
  </head>

    <% if :title == "Home" %>
    <body id="home-background">
    <% else %>
    <body>
    <% end %>
```

But it doesn't seem to work. The title will 'yield' and display in the address bar, but not in the if statement. I have also tried to put the yield(:title) in a variable and rails didn't like that. This is my first solo rails project, and I know This should be possible, but I can't find how to do it correctly, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: One note, :title is a symbol (starts with a colon).  Symbols are a little like strings, but have different qualities in memory.  To check if :title == "Home" is like saying "title" == "Home" - always false.  Learn more about symbols: http://www.troubleshooters.com/codecorn/ruby/symbols.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i wont recommend you for the `body` tag...but you can use a `wrapper` just after the `body` for a background image...it can be like this:-

**The only thing you will need is to create an instance variable(`@title`) to use below**

```
###application.html.erb

<body>

  <div class="<%= @title=="USER" ? 'user_wrapper' : 'default_wrapper' %>">

  </div>

</body>




 ##css

  .user_wrapper{
     background: url(user_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
   }

   .default_wrapper{
     background: url(default_background.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
   }
```

HOPE IT HELPS.. :)

Comment: I made a few tweaks to this, but the concept got me there. Perfect help. Thank you so much.

Comment: Great..you may accept my answer if it was helpful :).. @FalconBrazilT1